Where can I find static directory when deploying to vercel?
Usually, in any other hosting provider - after the app is built, I can see my static folder inside .next/static. For some reason, when deploying to vercel - this folder doesn't exist
Do you know where it is saved?
I'm using the pages router, if it means anything
Thanks!

In most hosting providers, they use a server, where you have access to the file system. On Vercel, that does not exist. You can read more about how Vercel "exposes" the dynamic and static parts of your apps on https://vercel.com/docs/build-output-api/v3 and other resources.
